# Get day, month, year from data in Lua

Tags: lua

Format of my data: 3 august 2018.

I need to get separately day, month and year from data aforementioned format.

Next fragment have been using for finding a day. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with error "attempt to concatenate field 'day' (a function value).":

```
local exampleArray = {data = "", day = "", month = "", year = ""}
exampleArray["day"]=string.gmatch(entitiesArray["data"], '%d*%.?%d+')
```

Maybe, it's a wrong regex. So, what an regex will be true for solving the problem?

Also, does another solving exist apart from using regex?

Comment: `s = "3 august 2018"; d, m, y = s:match"(%d+)[-/.%s]+(%w+)[-/.%s]+(%d+)"`

Comment: Hi @Egor I notice you typically answer in comments. Why not post as an answer so others know that question is resolved? Also, so the OP can mark as correct instead of also just leaving a comment?

Comment: @Brian - that's a long story...  BTW, feel free to post answers based on my comments, I'll remove my comments after they are not needed anymore.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, thanks. But I have problems with month. Anyway, I've understand the plot. So, 've written: exampleArray["day"]=exampleArray["data"]:match"(%d+)[-/.%s]"; exampleArray["month"]=string.gsub(exampleArray["data"], '[^a-z]', '' ); exampleArray["year"]=exampleArray["data"]:match('%d%d%d%d') .

Comment: @DumbSimon - What is the problem with month?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, Returns nil. Maybe, it's because input has russian symbols.

Comment: Yes, russian symbols are not matched with `%w`.  Use `[^%s%p]+` instead of `%w+`. Example: `s = "3 жараблября 2018"; d, m, y = s:match"(%d+)[-/.%s]+([^%s%p]+)[-/.%s]+(%d+)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input string is `3 august 2018`, then you want to split it into its three words, a word being defined as a run of nonwhitespace characters. The pattern that fits this description is this:

```
s = "3 august 2018"
d,m,y = s:match("(%S+)%s+(%S+)%s+(%S+)")
print(d,m,y)
```

Note the use of `match` instead of `gmatch`, which is meant to be used in loops.